# Can we use Apache Ignite as full-fledged SQL database?

Tags: ignite

If Yes, what are the pros and cons?

I knew this is an open ended question. But, I would like to hear different views on this.

Answer (score 1):

Apache Ignite is ANSI-99 compliant, it supports most SQL features.

But you should take into account, that it is a distributed database. Data should be [properly collocated](https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/distributed-joins) to make queries, containing joins work well.

You can operate on the same data from both SQL and Java API, which gives you great flexibility.